# Stack after pseudo Element behind headline (as box-shadow alternative)

Tags: css, z-index

I've the following problem: I want headlines with background and a box-shadow. Now, as firefox is not rendering transform rotate like a charm, I'm looking for an alternative.

```
h2 {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #006AB3;
  transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(-3deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  margin-bottom: rem-calc(50px);
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  z-index:1;
  &:after{
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            right:-10px;
            bottom:-10px;
            outline: 1px solid transparent;
            z-index: -1;
        }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gw64ove4/

Why is the pseudo after Element not stacked behind the headline? Are there any other workarounds for anti aliasing when using box-shadow on a rotated element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a span in H2 tag:

```
<h2>
<span>TEXT</span>
</h2>
```

and CSS for span like this:

```
span {display: block; position: relative; z-index: 10;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zLna2xLa/

Also you can try using **-moz-** prefixes

EG::

```
-moz-transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: Great! looks better now. **span** did a great job infact